# VirtualBox: vboxsf filesystem wrongly detected as readonly?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, mount, filesystems, read-only

I have **VirtualBox** (Windows XP host) running a **CentOS 6.0** virtual machine, with one **shared folder**.

Here is the list of mounted devices:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -l
...
www on /media/sf_www type vboxsf (gid=501,rw)
```

Looks like it's read/write.

Now if I try to write on this shared folder:

```
[root@localhost ~]# touch /media/sf_www/test
touch: cannot touch `/media/sf_www/test': Read-only file system
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

***Edit: just tried to manually mount it elsewhere, same problem:***

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount.vboxsf -w www /mnt/www
[root@localhost ~]# mount -l
...
www on /media/sf_www type vboxsf (gid=501,rw)
www on /mnt/www type vboxsf (rw)
[root@localhost ~]# touch /mnt/www/test
touch: cannot touch `/mnt/www/test': Read-only file system
```

*Note: the `www` folder is writeable on my host machine.*

Comment: In case you came here with similar errors creating *soft-links* see this question: https://superuser.com/questions/446362/why-cant-i-create-soft-link-on-vboxsf-file-system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Actually, I changed my shared folder from *readonly* to "read/write" while the machine was running, then rebooted the machine.

The solution was simply to properly shut down the machine, then start it again.

Comment: Thanks for this! Was starting to run out of hairs to pull out of my head - you saved me from having to purchase a wig :)

Comment: Glad I could save your hair :-)

Comment: Doing a full shutdown rather than just a reboot does the trick there... thanks!